# HTML code is a not in a correct format in emebr js

Tags: ember.js

Im try to code this **html** code  for the **ember js** format, but i cant do it, how can i fix it?

```
<h5>Thursday. May. 05. 2017</h5>
<div class="progress-bar position" data-percent="48" data-duration="1000" data-color="#6a6f77,#5fb756"><script>$(".progress-bar").loading()</script></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I a guessing you are trying to add data-tags

For That you have to add

```
Ember.LinkComponent.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-dismiss']
});
```

above line to your route file.

And if you want  data-percent="48" to be dynamic just change it to data-percent="{{value-from-controller}}".

I could not fully understood your problem , Let me know if this help or you want something else.

[link on how you can add data tags](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_adding-data-attributes)

Comment: sir, we can add the emebr js to normal `html` codes structure, just example like a button code.. its is a good?

Comment: Yes we can add normal html to Ember js template. Ember uses handlebars for for templating.
I am not able to understand your problem, Can you please tell what do you want?

Comment: sir, my problem is  i don't know how to add emebr js fomat to the html code, look this im always use this format `<button type="button" class="btn  btn-circle btn-xl"></button>` that is better for emebr js?or im wrong ?look this one http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/button this is not my structure .. what is better?

Comment: You can add <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xl"></button> into your ember and it is completely fine.

Comment: ,sir Thank you for the guide me